# Git create branch from another branch. Send pull requests for both?

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch, rebase, pull-request

1. I created a branch and sent a pull request on those changes, let's call it branch A.
2. Then I created a branch B while I was still on my branch A. After some changes, I wanted to send a pull request for those changes and saw the commit of branch A (the one I sent a pull request) in the latest commits of branch B.

How should I manage that?

- Can I send a pull request for branch B as well? Will it have side effects?
- Can I instead rebase the commits on the last master merge and rename the commit to the name of the changes on branch B? Would that also remove the commit on the branch A that I sent a pull request on?
- If I need other changes on the branch A before the pull request is accepted, can I still rebase/squash the commits of branch A without affecting branch B?

I suppose I should normally make sure I'm on the master again before creating another branch to develop a new feature so it doesn't happen again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found another way that I like very much, which is **cherry-picking**.

1. Do the pull request for the branch that came from master (A).
2. Get the commit hash of the branch that is not based on the master (B).

   ```
   git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"
   ```
3. (Optional) Delete the old branch (B) if you want to keep the same name:

   ```
   git branch -D B
   ```
4. Create a new branch from the master:

   ```
   git checkout -b B
   ```
5. Cherry pick the changes (merge the changes into the new branch):

   ```
   git cherry-pick HASH_OF_B (noted in step 2)
   ```
6. Merge if you have conflicts, then end the cherry-pick:

   ```
   git cherry-pick --continue
   ```
7. Send a pull request for this new branch based correctly on the master.

What I like about this is that the master branch stays in perfect shape (perfectly clean) and it's very simple to do. We can also squash the commits in the branches without worrying.

Answer (score 1):

**Can I send a pull request for branch B as well? Will it have side effects?**

Let's draw a quick picture

```
X --- X --- X --- X <--(master)
       \
        A1 -- A2 <--(A)
          \
           B1 -- B2 -- B3 <--(B)
```

I assume the PR for `A` is still outstanding, so `A1` is a difference between `master` and `B`.  If nothing in `B` is dependent on `A1`, then this is conceptually not good; you don't want approval/merge of `B` to depend on acceptance/potential premature release of the changes in `A1`.

Now, if the PR for `A` gets approved, then after that merge `A1` ceases to be a difference; and you could argue "no harm, no foul"; but still it would be best if independent branches were independently rooted from `master`.

**Can I instead rebase the commits on the last master merge and rename the commit to the name of the changes on branch B? Would that also remove the commit on the branch A that I sent a pull request on?**

Taking the second part of that first: rebasing does not remove commits from the repo; this is a (seemingly common) misconception.  Because `A1` is reachable from branch `A`, it will be unaffected by a rebase of `B`.  *However,* you should take care when rebasing to avoid creating a duplicate of the `A1` commit as this would defeat the purpose of the rebase.

```
git rebase --onto master A B
```

should give you

```
                      B1' -- B2' -- B3' <--(B)
                    /
X --- X --- X --- X <--(master)
       \
        A1 -- A2 <--(A)
         \
          B1 --- B2 --- B3
```

(Note that I've shown `B1`, `B2`, and `B3` in this diagram for clarity to reinforce the point that rebasing *does not delete commits*.  Since no refs point to them, you won't see them unless you know how to look for them, and they would be excluded from `push` operations, etc.; and eventually they may get garbage collected.  But right after the rebase, in your local repo you could do something like `git log B@{1}` and see that they're still there)

Remember that if `B` has ever been pushed, this can cause problems for other developers (because while no commits are removed from the repo, this does make commits that *used to be* reachable from `B` become *no longer reachable* from `B`, and that's not good.

See "recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` documentation, and if this doesn't seem to be a problem then you can rebase.  Just remember that you need to re-test the rebased `B` since its tree is in a uniquely new state.  (IMO best practice would be to re-test the intermediate commits as well.)

**If I need other changes on the branch A before the pull request is accepted, can I still rebase/squash the commits of branch A without affecting branch B?**

There are at least a couple variations on this question.

If you have *not* rebased `B` away from `A`, then any rebasing operation that would rewrite or replace `A1` may leave you in an unexpected state, because `B` will still point through `A1` (not `A1'` that was created in a rebase, or `A1A2` in the case of a squash, or whatever).

If you *have* rebased `B` away from `A`, then you can do whatever you like to `A` without further effect on `B`.  Again just be aware of the risks of rewriting history that has been pushed.